# How to make a custom shape with properties in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

How to create a custom shape in WPF? For example, I am trying to draw multiple symbols connected between each other on a cavas. I would need each symbol to change the color as well. How would I create let's say a custom shape that can change colors. Let's say the following two shapes I would like to make into one. how would I go to encapsulate them

```
<Ellipse x:Name="theEllipse"
                 Height="89"
                 Width="82"
                 Fill="Black"
                 Canvas.Left="32"
                 Canvas.Top="75" />

<Ellipse x:Name="theEllipse"
                 Height="89"
                 Width="82"
                 Fill="Black"
                 Canvas.Left="32"
                 Canvas.Top="75" />
```

The solution provided below does work with the ellipses however,
it does not work with the following figures:

```
        <Line X1="10"
              Y1="50"
              X2="50"
              Y2="50"
              Stroke="Black"
              StrokeThickness="2" />
        <Line X1="15"
              Y1="55"
              X2="45"
              Y2="55"
              Stroke="Black"
              StrokeThickness="2" />

        <Line X1="20"
              Y1="60"
              X2="40"
              Y2="60"
              Stroke="Black"
              StrokeThickness="2" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in Blend.

1. Select the two ellipses/shapes in the *Objects and Timeline* window
2. Right-click on the selection
3. Go to *Path* -> *Make compound path*

[image]

---

**Update 2017-04-10**

If you want this operation to work with all shapes and lines, you have to make sure your elements are inside a `Canvas`, not a `Grid` or `StackPanel`. The parent container of the elements matters.

So in the case of the 3 lines, wrap them inside a `Canvas` and run the *Make Compound Path* operation again.

```
<Canvas>
    <Line X1="10"
            Y1="50"
            X2="50"
            Y2="50"
            Stroke="Black"
            StrokeThickness="2" />
    <Line X1="15"
            Y1="55"
            X2="45"
            Y2="55"
            Stroke="Black"
            StrokeThickness="2" />

    <Line X1="20"
            Y1="60"
            X2="40"
            Y2="60"
            Stroke="Black"
            StrokeThickness="2" />
</Canvas>
```

This is what it should look like after:

```
<Canvas>
    <Path Data="M1,1 L41,1 M6.00001,6 L36,6 M11,11 L31,11"
            Height="12"
            Canvas.Left="9"
            Stretch="Fill"
            Stroke="Black"
            StrokeThickness="2"
            Canvas.Top="49"
            UseLayoutRounding="False"
            Width="42" />
</Canvas>
```

Comment: By the way just tried to do the same with the lines and it did not work

Comment: I am doing exactly that. All my line elements are inside a canvas. I select three lines, right click on them path-> make a compound path. And they turn into one line. Not sure what am i doing wrong

Comment: Try it on an empty `Page` or `UserControl`. There maybe some other panel getting in the way.